# Problem in Ping or SSH connect to docker container

Tags: docker, ssh, lucene, ping, pylucene

I am new to docker. I installed docker on Windows 10. Also, I have installed SSH on my win.

I have a pylucene docker container. When I check the status of my docker container, it is Up.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE            COMMAND       CREATED       STATUS        PORTS     NAMES
d70d6f0ed7ab   coady/pylucene   "/bin/bash"   4 weeks ago   Up 3 hours              amazing_dubinsky
```

Also, I have no problem with executing it and working with its shell.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> docker exec -it d70d6f0ed7ab /bin/bash
root@d70d6f0ed7ab:/usr/src# python
Python 3.9.2 (default, Mar 31 2021, 12:13:11)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import lucene
>>> print(lucene.VERSION)
8.8.1
>>>
```

but when I found its IP and try to ping this docker container from my win, the result is just timeout!

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> docker inspect -f "{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}" d70d6f0ed7ab                               
172.17.0.3
PS C:\Windows\system32> ping 172.17.0.3                                                                                 
Pinging 172.17.0.3 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 172.17.0.3:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

Also SSH connect to this container fails,

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> ssh root@172.17.0.3                                                                             
ssh: connect to host 172.17.0.3 port 22: Connection timed out
PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve], including source code (as text) and commands (as text) needed to reproduce the issue?  This question contains four image files; what do you do with those images?

Comment: (I tend to think of a Docker container as a single process; that single process usually isn't an ssh daemon, and it doesn't make sense to "ssh into", "ping", or "get a shell in" a process.)

Answer (score 0):

The [`coady/pylucene`](https://hub.docker.com/r/coady/pylucene/Dockerfile) image is based on `python:latest`

- [`python:latest`](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/83b7e0cf623605178c0e7c42ee81fe758fc7e6f1/3.10-rc/buster/Dockerfile#L7) is based on `buildpack-deps:buster`

  - [`buildpack-deps:buster`](https://github.com/docker-library/buildpack-deps/blob/65d69325ad741cea6dee20781c1faaab2e003d87/debian/buster/Dockerfile#L7-L52) is based on  `buildpack-deps:scm`

    - [`buildpack-deps:scm`](https://github.com/docker-library/buildpack-deps/blob/65d69325ad741cea6dee20781c1faaab2e003d87/debian/buster/scm/Dockerfile#L7) is based on  `buildpack-deps:buster-curl`

      - [`buildpack-deps:buster-curl`](https://github.com/docker-library/buildpack-deps/blob/98a5ab81d47a106c458cdf90733df0ee8beea06c/debian/buster/curl/Dockerfile#L7) is based on  `debian:buster`

        - [`debian:buster`](https://github.com/debuerreotype/docker-debian-artifacts/blob/0590e3720f7f87992202bfcca4c13c374ff304bc/buster/Dockerfile) is based [Debian 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian#Sarge_and_later_releases_(2005%E2%80%93present))

And... debian 10 does not have [`openssh-server` installed/active](https://linuxhint.com/enable_ssh_debian_10/) by default.

Plus, as [mentioned here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/#i-cannot-ping-my-containers):

> Docker Desktop for Windows can’t route traffic to Linux containers.
> However, you can ping the Windows containers.

In other words, those "problems" you are experiencing are perfectly expected.